# OnClick Javascript Confirmation Window

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

Why does the below still delete even if I hit cancel on the alert popup? What am I missing?

```
onClick="confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete '.esc_attr($this->event_name).'?\')"
```

Comment: more code please... this code is not sufficient to answer your question...

Comment: @FahimParkar. Actually it does, see my answer.

Comment: @FahimParkar - Sure it is, at least, three of us have answered so far...

Comment: @nnnnnn. and two of us commented... =)

Comment: @gdoron - And Fahim went ahead and answered too (and somebody even upvoted that answer).

Comment: LOL!!! I think most funniest moment on stackoverflow I have seen =))

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you return `false` from your `onclick` handler it will cancel the default action of the click. So try this:

```
onClick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete '.esc_attr($this->event_name).'?\')"
```

That will return whatever value the `confirm()` returns, i.e., `true` if you click OK and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Check below..

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">
function checkMe() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure")) {
        alert("Clicked Ok");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Clicked Cancel");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<input type=submit value="Press Me" onClick="return checkMe()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Write what you want to do in `Click Ok`.

### Good Luck!!!

Comment: I thought you said there wasn't enough information to answer this question?

Comment: @nnnnnn. the truth is that I upvoted his comment, it took me two seconds to realize it's sufficient.... **lol**

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the value from that `confirm`:

```
onClick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete '.esc_attr($this->event_name).'?\')"
```

So if you click cancel it will be equal to `onClick="return false"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value from that confirm:

```
onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make sure to use `return false;` when the user clicks on the cancel button, in your Javascript code.  Otherwise, the script won't cancel the rest of the process.